# error while deploying my django to the digital ocean server with postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, web-deployment, digital-ocean, droplet

i cloned my github repository to the remote machine and i done the following changes to the files

- changed allowed host to server's ip
- cleared migration files which was created in my local machine because that caused me many error
- collected static files
- sucessfully migrated

but when i run server i throws the following error

```
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value: relation "blog_short_intro" does not exist
LINE 1: ...."profile_pic", "blog_short_intro"."content" FROM "blog_shor...
```

when i open the admin panel i can able to view the database tables
but when i try to enter any of the tables that gives me error

pictures

error in homepage
[image: Error in homepage]
admin panel
[image: admin panel]
admin panel error when entered into any table
[image: admin panel error when entered into any table]

Comment: Are you using the same database in both places you are running the app? It is acting like the tables don't exist... if you erased the migrations folder but are using a pre-existing database it will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have to use the database name same as our project name then this error will be resolved